# Rewrite query var on postname

Tags: url-rewriting, query-variable

I'm trying to do a rewrite, so that the query var is going to look pretty:

This is the URL structure I got now:

```
example.com/post-type-archive/post-name/?subpage=about
```

This is what I want:

```
example.com/post-type-archive/post-name/about
```

Please note, that `post_name` is changing depending what site you're on. All the answers I've found so far, didn't consider that.

This is my current code:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'subpage';
    return $vars;
});
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%subpage%', '([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('[^post-type-archive/]([^/]+)','index.php?name=$matches[1]&subpage=$matches[2]','top');
});
```

This makes the page return an 404 - page not found page.

And yes... I have flushed the rewrite rules after every changes I've made.

---

### EDIT

I got it to work by using this:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%subpage', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^post-type-archive/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=post-type-archive&name=$matches[1]&subpage=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
});
```

The only problem now, is that pagination don't work anymore on `post-type-archive`.

Comment: How are you using `subpage` in your code? If you rewrite the URL like this you need to use `get_query_var( 'subpage' )`. `$_GET['subpage']` won't work anymore.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to tell that my code, returns an 404 - page not found page

Answer (score 0):

So, first up, I don't believe that you need a rewrite tag in this situation, so you can omit that.

The issue, I believe, with the remaining code is that your rewrite rule is only capturing 1 match (because there's only one set of `()`), so `subpage` isn't receiving a value. <del>Additionally, your rule seems to *exclude* any posts of your post type ( because of the `^`)</del>. *Actually*, it seems to exclude any URLs where the post name begins with any of the letters `p`,`o`,`s`,`t`,`_`,`t`,`y`,`p`,`e`.

I believe your rewrite rule should be:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'post_type/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&subpage=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

Then you just need to make sure that in your template you're accessing the subpage value correctly. `$_GET['subpage']` will no longer work. Instead you need to use `get_query_var( 'subpage' )`.

Also make sure you re-save your Permalinks settings.

Comment: Hi Jacob. Thanks for your answer. After trying your code, I no longer get a 404 error page, but instead it redirects me straight to the post_name/ page

Comment: What does `subpage` do, by the way? What is the subpage? Something you do in your template?

Comment: On the division-page, there is a submenu: About, Latest news, Contact. This menu-structure is the same on all division-pages, but the content within each submenu-pages are different for each individual division